# " Cannot use import statement outside a module" error while using jest and react

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am trying to make a test using jest and react-testing-library but when I try to render the app inside a test block I am getting this error:

```
...{import axios from './lib/axios.js';
                                                                                 

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

After a little research I see that jest ignores everything in node_modules when it transforms modules using babel-jest. Is there a way to allow the axios module to be transformed?

**Here is my package.json file**

```
{
  "name": "weather_app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "start": "webpack serve --config webpack.config.js",
    "react-dev": "webpack --mode development --watch",
    "server-dev": "npx nodemon server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.19.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.2.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.2.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^18.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "axios": "^1.1.2",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "mysql2": "^2.3.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "url": "^0.11.0"
  }
}
```

**And my .babelrc file**

```
    {
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    ["@babel/preset-react", {"runtime": "automatic"}],
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
  ]
}
```

I do not have any other config files for jest or babel

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution. You can add a property to your jest.config.js file and specify modules from node modules to transform specifically but still ignore the rest of node modules. To tell babel-jest to transform axios it looked like this:

```
transformIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!(axios)/)']
```

Answer (score 1):

[This axios issue (#5106)](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5106) helped me (just downgrade axios to v0.27.2 and it works).